# Changing the date format in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I'm working on redHat linux.

*I've a file which looks like :*

$vi filename

Jan,1,00:00:01,someone checked your file

Jan,3,09:38:02,applebee

Jan,16,10:20:03, ****************

Jan,18,03:04:03, ***************

*I want the output to look like:*

2015/01/01,00:00:01,someone checked your file

2015/01/03,3,09:38:02,applebee

2015/01/16,16,10:20:03, ****************

2015/01/18,03:04:03, ***************

*Please help me to do this. Thanks*

Comment: I'm a new bee to linux world. I don't know how to proceed further. 
Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU date, try:

```
$ awk -F, '{cmd="date -d \""$1" "$2"\" +%Y/%m/%d"; cmd|getline d; print d","$3","$4; close(cmd)}' file
2015/01/01,00:00:01,someone checked your file
2015/01/03,09:38:02,applebee
2015/01/16,10:20:03, ****************
2015/01/18,03:04:03, ***************
```

This approach cannot be used with the BSD (OSX) version of `date` because it does not support any comparable `-d` option.

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over lines of input, breaking each line into fields.

- `-F,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator
- `cmd="date -d \""$1" "$2"\" +%Y/%m/%d"`

  This creates a string variable, `cmd`, and contains a `date` command.  I am assuming that you have GNU `date`.
- `cmd|getline d`

  This runs the command and captures the output in variable `d`.
- `print d","$3","$4`

  This prints the output that you asked for.
- `close(cmd)`

  This closes the command.

Comment: Thanks John, your solution was helpful